# Does Kubernetes allocates resources if the resource limit is above node capacity?

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to know, does scheduler considers resource limits when scheduling a pod? 
For example, of scheduler schedules 4 pods in a specific node with total capacity <200mi, 400m> and the total resource limits of those pods are <300mi, 700m>, what will be happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only resource *requests* are considered during scheduling.  This can result in a node being overcommitted.  ([Managing Compute Resources for Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#how-pods-with-resource-requests-are-scheduled) in the Kubernetes documentation says a little more.)

In your example, say your node has 1 CPU and 2 GB of RAM, and you've scheduled 4 pods that request 0.2 CPU and 400 MB RAM each.  Those all "fit" (requiring 0.8 CPU and 1.6 GB RAM total) so they get scheduled.  If any individual pod exceeds its own limit, its CPU usage will be throttled or memory allocation will fail or the process will be killed.  But, say all 4 of the pods try to allocate 600 MB of RAM: none individually exceeds its limits, but in aggregate it's more memory than the system has, so the underlying Linux kernel will invoke its out-of-memory killer and shut down processes to free up space.  You might see this as a pod restarting for no apparent reason.

Comment: Also, if the total resource limits of RAM exceed 2 GB, what will be happended?

Comment: Neither the limits nor actual current memory usage are considered during scheduling.